# API Request failed status 502 in Outsystems

Tags: api, rest, outsystems

I tried to build a simple WMS Mobile App and consume API from a PAT (Personal Access Token) using Outsystems.
I am using Outsystems Service Studio Version 11.53.18 / Build 61343

[image: Get Procurement List API]

[image: Failed Request Status 502]

tbh I don't understand how to solve this. I'm new in using Outsystems. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Status 502 is an http error code. This means something went wrong on the side of the service. This could be due to wrong input data. Check the documentation/support of the service you are using.

Comment: Yes, @MarkBaijens is right. I suggest testing the API inputs in OutSystems Service Studio first. Make sure you get 200 OK there first, then you publish and test user's input (if that's the case)